# EN 300 328 CE radio certification with power limit

Tags: rf, radio, fcc, certification, ce

We have developed product for Malesia country, where we need local SIRIM certificate.

RF module we used in our product is 2.4Ghz wifi mesh, with max 30dbm (1 watt) output power capacity.

To get SIRIM we need to submit CE report of product to SIRIM. We have done EMC testing as per CE, but have some doubt in radio related testing as per EN 300 328.

Q1) at what power level we need to set in our radio to do this EN 300 328 testing. Do we need to set 100mW,500mw or 1W?

Q2) Malesia max limit is 500mW.  Do we need to set 500mW or is anything less than 500mw ok?

Q3) If we set 100mW and completed CE test and later in final product we can not go more than 100mW since Malesia have till 500mW.

Q4) EN 300 328 "maximum power test " say 20dBm (100mW is max,) then what does it mean we can not test a product more than 100mw if they has capacity more than 100mW.

Q5) If I test at 500mW then in EN 300 328 "maximum transmit test ' is it going to fail?

Please advise.
Below is the link of sample report of EN 300 328 taken from internet.
http://processors.wiki.ti.com/images/8/8c/ER3N2752_R01_EN300328_Texas_WG7835-B0.pdf

Comment: Test for the case you need to use in your products. 500mW is quite high - at that level I'd worry more about health regulations than radio ones.

Comment: You have to comply with your regulations. The regulation says 100mW max, set your module to 100mW or less.

Answer (score 1):

"4.3.1.2.3 Limit
The maximum RF output power for adaptive Frequency Hopping equipment shall be equal to or less than 20 dBm.
The maximum RF output power for non-adaptive Frequency Hopping equipment shall be declared by the supplier. See
clause 5.3.1 m). The maximum RF output power for this equipment shall be equal to or less than the value declared by
the supplier. This declared value shall be equal to or less than 20 dBm.
This limit shall apply for any combination of power level and intended antenna assembly. "